# IBM MQ Server Configuration

Tags: ibm-mq

I recently implemented some minor changes in my qm.ini configuration. My question is, if there is one or more error in the configuration file, can MQ sort out only the wrong config, or is the whole qm.ini get omitted?

Example:

```
Channels: 

MaxChannels=3000

MaxActiveChannels=300 

TCP: 

KeepAlive=Yes

ListenerBacklog=7O0
```

The wrong config is in ListenerBacklog.

Is all config omitted, or only the ListenerBacklog not implemented ?

Answer (score 0):

No, whole qm.ini file will not be ignored because of one erroneous value. MQ will read all the attributes in the ini file. In your case ListenerBacklog value might get truncated to 7 as there is a non-numeric character after 7.